# NetBeans and Git: I did install Git plugin but does not connect to repo after initializing, nor adds files

Tags: git, netbeans, repository

I have NetBeans 7.01 and installed the Git plugin from the plugins panel

After installation was completed and NetBeans restarted
I have right clicked on one of my projects, selected "versioning" and initizialized a git repo; I chose to have the .git folder inside the root of the project

However, that didn't do nothing. I checked the output terminal, all it says is:

```
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.50.35 Initializing ...
Initializing repository
Creating git D:\Siti\Current\nellaterradisandokan.com\content\themes/.git directory
git init D:\Siti\Current\nellaterradisandokan.com\content\themes
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.50.37 Ignoring...
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.50.39 Initializing ... finished.
ignoring D:\Siti\Current\nellaterradisandokan.com\content\themes\nbproject\private 
nbproject/private
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.50.39 Ignoring... finished.
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.51.08 Connecting
==[IDE]== 19-gen-2012 4.51.08 Connecting finished.
```

however, no files were actually added to git, while they should have been automatically..: I can't add files manually because the project is not connected to Git. If I right click again on the project and try to connect, the console tries to connect, says "Connecting finished", but nothing is connected.

from the output above looks like it's ignoring the whole folder where the files are, but why?

How do I make this work? I'm new to Git.

Comment: Does it actually succeed when initializing the repo? That is, does the `.git` directory exist in your project's directory? If so, is there a `.gitignore` file in your project's directory?

Comment: there are both, a folder .git and a .gitignore; the .gitignore contains only the path to the netbeans project files (nbproject), not my actual files

Comment: I solved the problem by uninstalling NetBeans and resintalling it... looks like some bug or some borked installation... works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run in a problem similar to mine, you could try uninstalling NetBeans and reinstalling it. That solved my problem. Not really a solution or an explaination for what happened, but at least you might get rid of your headaches until Git will be better supported by Netbeans.