# Changing GIT project directory in Netbeans - Git context menu does not appear

Tags: java, git, netbeans

I've faced weird problem in my `NetBeans 8.1`.

After cloning Git repository in default directory (`My documents/NetBeansProject/ProjectDir`) I'm able to access the Git context menu (for example, `Git -> Commit`).

However, if I change this directory into another (let it be `C:/Projects/ProjectDir`), the context menu option `Git` disappears from right-click menu on project.

Why does it work like this?

I've found similiar case:
[NetBeans not showing GIT in the right-click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139839/netbeans-not-showing-git-in-the-right-click-menu)
where (in comments) @VonC suggests passing the `git-dir` argument. How can I do that?

---

**EDIT:**
As suggested in comments, I've used the external `git` command.
`git status` in both `C:/Projects/` and `My documents` shows as follows:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

`git remote -v` also does have the same output in both directories.

Comment: Is there a `.git` subfolder in `C:/Projects/ProjectDir`? If not, you would need to clone your repo to `C:/Projects/ProjectDir`.

Comment: There is this directory. As I have mentioned in my question - I have alreade cloned project from Git. Everything seems the same in those two directories - the only one difference is that I cant access `Git` option in context menu - and thanks to that, I can't even commit to Git anymore...

Comment: Right now I have cloned the same projects in those two different locations. Effect: I have `Git` option on project from `My documents` and the other one does not have it. I've inspected directories physically on disk and the `.git` directory seems fine in both cases.

Comment: So when you go to `C:/Projects/ProjectDir` in command-line, does a `git status` works? Does a `git remote -v` returns the same output in that folder as it would in `My documents/NetBeansProject/ProjectDir`?

Comment: Answers to your question are in my post. I suppose now it's NB bug?

Comment: It looks that way, indeed.

Comment: Maybe there is some workaround for this problem. You did mention about the `git-dir` option - maybe this could help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105768/discussion-between-deem-and-vonc).

Comment: Not sure it could help here, unless you modify the code of the NB git plugin. Maybe try and launch NB after setting the environment variable GIT_DIR first? Sorry, no chat at work (blocked)